# How to get more docker hierarchy info?

Tags: docker

I installed dockerviz and set alias
But what I get from it

```
dockviz images -t kong:latest
└─5ce182fc4fde Virtual Size: 98.4 MB Tags: kong:latest
```

And

```
dockviz images -d | dot -Tpng -o kong:latest
```

shows nothing.

Docker inspect would give me much more info.

How does dockviz work?
Are there any other tools?

Comment: Just read sparsely the [documentation](https://github.com/justone/dockviz) of this project I didn't know. Did you try to open the file `kong:latest` you created in the current folder with your last command using an image viewer (e.g. your browser) ? I suppose you wanted to use `-o kong_latest.png` which would better identify an image file, although I think you will get info about all your images, not only `kong:latest`

Comment: With png added I got nothing again.

Comment: Did you actually open the png file that is supposed to be generated ?